# Make different color for a specific value with ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to make a different color for a specific value with `ggplot2`. Here is the code what I am working on.

```
    ggplot(out, aes(XX, pct_trips_w_item, colour=channel2)) +
  geom_point()  +   ggtitle("sample") +     xlab("X")
```

For a specific value `X = "(18,20]"` and `pct_trips_w_item = corresponding value in my data`, I want to make different color. I do not want to make a label in the legend for the value.

How to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work for you.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, color = Species)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(data = iris[15,], aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, 
                                   colour="red", size = 10))
```

[image]